# First request from windows server on IIS is too slow

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2016

I do request for another service from my server and the first one is too slow it takes around 8-10 seconds. Second one and next 500ms. Why can it be? It happeans every first request per 20 minutes.
I use Windows server 2016, IIS.
It seems for me that something is down every 20 minutes if there weren't a request and then up for the first request and it takes some time to up

Just loged some requests time

Comment: IIS has a idle time-out property that is by default set to 20 minutes. This means that if no request comes for your site for 20 minutes of inactivity, IIS would kill the worker process to free-up resources. You can try to cancel Idle Time-out: https://community.sisense.com/t5/knowledge/cancel-iis-timeout-and-recycling/ta-p/9034#:~:text=The%20default%20value%20for%20idle,worker%20processes%20are%20consistently%20idle.

Comment: The request is from my server and its active, a lot of users uses it.

Comment: Try using Advanced Logging for IIS to see the details when the request is obtained : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging. Or use Event Viewer to monitor what happens when IIS get slow.